# top: 0px; bottom: 0px; doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't the following display a 200px-high blue block?

```
<div style="position: absolute; height: 500px;">
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background-color: Green; position: relative;">
        a</div>
    <div style="width: 200px; background-color: Blue; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: relative;">
        b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the question is extremely localized (unlikely to help anyone else), and it is a "debug my code for me" request.

Comment: It is likely to help anyone making the same mistake I did thinking that `bottom` behaves the same for `relative` as for `absolute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The positional properties (top, left, right, bottom) on elements with a relative position indicate offsets from its current position.  You set a top and a bottom of 0 on a relatively positioned element.  You basically told it to go nowhere.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to my question. But I'm still looking for a source for that.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Comment: I always forget about this and I always come back to this answer.  I'm not sure why it isn't more accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You've not set a height on the div, the only div you have set a height on has it set to 500px

Also in what way were you expecting the top and bottom to work... You've said they don't work as expected, but they are there to set the position from top left.

> This property specifies the top position of the element including padding, scrollbar, border and margin.

Quoted from: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_top.asp

A side note is that you don't need to put the px on there so `top:0; bottom:0;`

Comment: But top and bottom are set to 0.

Comment: The top (bottom, left and right) properties set the relative position of the element from its parent. So your code is trying to set the element to nowhere. See the link to w3 schools in my post for a more complete explanation

Comment: You do realize that when `position:absolute` my code _would_ work. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Position should be set to `absolute` for an element to recalculate its dimensions relative to its relative parent. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/xvbmS/).

Comment: Isn't `relative` the same except it starts from where the previous one ended?

Comment: Not really — @cinnamon says it best: it offsets compared to where it would normally be. `absolute` positioning allows the directional position properties to take reference from the nearest `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative` ancestor.